# TAB completion not working in jupyter notebook and giving the error "NotImplementedError"

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython

Code completion or TAB completion is not working in Jupyter notebook and at the same time Jupyter is giving the error "NotImplementedError". Jupyter and ipython were installed using `pip` and were upgraded. The keywords are not getting highlighted either.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using python3, may be you can try
"pip install parso==0.1.1". I had the same issue and was resolved by this.

Reference link: https://bugs.python.org/issue32187